# Unique custom field - contact creation

Tags: civimember, contacts, custom-fields, duplicate-contacts

I want to add a custom field that we use as an ID from a 3rd party. I need to ensure this value is unique as a way to prevent duplicates. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

The "external identifier" field on contact records is available so you don't need a custom field. It won't allow duplicates.